# How to find impulse response using residue MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a transfer function H(s) which looks like this: 1/(s.^2+s+1), which does not have any real roots, only complex ones. How can I find its impulse response for t = 0:0.001:10? I know that I need to express H as a product of two first-oreder polynomials and then use the method of partial fractions to express H as a sum of two terms (using residue function). Here where I got stuck, I used residue but it didn't help much, here is my code:

```
t=[0:0.001:10];
f = 0:0.001:2;
j = sqrt(-1);

num = [0 0 1];
den = [1 1 1];
[r,p,k] = residue(num,den)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using symbolic computation:

```
>> syms s;
>> H = 1/(s.^2+s+1);
>> h = ilaplace(H)
h =
(2*3^(1/2)*exp(-t/2)*sin((3^(1/2)*t)/2))/3
```

If you want to plot the symbolic function `h` on [0 10]:

```
>> ezplot(h, [0 10])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Coefficients of numerator and denominator are the coefficients of corresponding ODE problem.

```
eq = @(t,z) [z(2); 1-z(1)-z(2)];
[t,y] = ode45(eq,[0,10],[0,0])
plot(t,y)
```

[image]